# Rspreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to use the rspreadsheet gem, first I tried with bundler but each time there is this error: `require ': cannot load such file - rspreadsheet.

So I installed the gem directly and when I run my program to test:

```rb
workbook = Rspreadsheet.open('./print.ods')

sheet = workbook.worksheet(1)
```

It tells me: uninitialized constant Rspreadsheet (NameError).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script is named `script.rb` and you have already run `bundle install` could you try running `bundle exec ruby script.rb` to see if that works?